# Making JqGrid cells editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My goal is to inline edit cells in a data grid using JQuery and JqGrid. I got the grid to populate based on an ajax request and json reponse. Unfortunately I can't get the cells to become editable when clicking on rows.

I tried both Chrome and Safari and did two days of research and still no luck. The links I used below didn't help:

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

Following the tutorials I added an onRowSelect event that would call editRow and set the value to true. However it never works and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css"/>

    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                        url:'http://localhost:8080/jblog/messages',
                        datatype:'json',
                        jsonReader: {
                            root: 'rows',
                            repeatitems: false,
                            page:  'currentPage',
                            total: 'totalRecords'
                        },
                        mtype:'GET',
                        colNames:['Message ID', 'Message Content'],
                        colModel:[
                            {name:'messageId', index:'messageId'},
                            {name:'content', index:'content', width:'400'}
                        ],
                        viewrecords:true,
                        caption:'My first grid',
                        rowNum:30,
                        rowList:[10,20,30],
                        pager: '#pager',
                        sortname: 'messageId',
                        onSelectRow: function(id){
                            console.log('onSelectRow');
                            editRow(id);
                            },
                        editurl:'http://localhost:8080/jblog/messages'
                    });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
           var lastSelection;

           function editRow(id) {
               console.log("editRow");
               if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
                   console.log("setRowToEdit");
                   var grid = $("#list");
                   grid.restoreRow(lastSelection);
                   console.log("id " + id);
                   grid.editRow(id, true);
                   lastSelection = id;
               }
           }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error in your code is:

- you have to include [editable: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) property in the columns which you need to edit.

Additionally you should do following changes in the code:

- you should include `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` line before `<html>` which declare the dialect of HTML/XHTML which you use. If you use HTML5 dialect the line will be just `<!DOCTYPE html>`. In you case it seems can be the line `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` which corresponds XHTML 1.0 Strict. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file) for more details.
- I recommend you reduce the number of global variables. The variable `lastSelection` and the function `editRow` should be just in outer scope of `onSelectRow`. So you can move there inside of `$(document).ready(function() {/*here!!!*/});` block. I would recommend you better to use anonymous functions and place the code of `editRow` directly in the code of `onSelectRow`. By the way you can use `$(this)` instead of `$("#list")` inside of `onSelectRow`. It makes the code a little bit quickly and improves the maintenance of the code because you can easier cut & paste the code fragments.
- you should never use prefixes like `http://localhost:8080/` in the Ajax requests (see `url` and `editurl` options). Instead of that you should use `url:'/jblog/messages'` or `url:'jblog/messages'` URLs. Access to another server as the current server from which the current page are loaded or access of another port is prohibited because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of Ajax.
- I recommend you always use `gridview: true` jqGrid options which can improve performance of the grid.

Comment: I removed the DocType because I had issues pasting code in StackOverflow. The example for the editable row don't mention needing to specify individual columns unless you want some editable and some not.

Comment: @user1306537: In [the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) you'll find simple rules how to format the code. The lines like `<!DOCTYPE html>` can be easy included on the stackoverflow too. What is wrong with the example? I would only replace `jQuery('#rowed3')` to `$(this)`.

Comment: @user1306537. What is your current code? Do you replaced `{name:'content', index:'content', width:'400'}` to `{name:'content', index:'content', width:'400', editable: true}`? You can just append your current question with the current code which you use. What problem you have exactly? Is the editing mode will be not started or you can't save the changes?

Comment: The code above is my current code. The editRow function should make the row cells editable. I can't even get that to happen. I checked and all the functions are being called but the cells aren't editable. I'm using the exact same code in the examples in the JqGrid documentation.

Comment: @user1306537: I still don't see `editable: true` property in the column definition. The method `editRow` start editing mode only the for the columns which are marked in `colModel` as `editable: true`. So you can for example allow the user to modify the text from `content` column, but not from `messageId`. The default value of `editable` property is `false`. So the `editRow` along do nothing.

Comment: @user1306537: You are welcome! It's a standard error of people who start usage of jqGrid.